# What does the command 'catkin_init_workspace' do?

Tags: ros, create, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In reading different accounts of how to create a ROS workspace (in Hydro), I encountered a discrepancy. In the ROS tutorial sequence, a command 'catkin_init_workspace' is executed before going on to the 'build' process. In other accounts of the process, this step is not mentioned. I have not been able to find detailed documentation on this command. What exactly does it do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187084/what-does-the-command-%27catkin_init_workspace%27-do?/) by [mosfet2u](https://answers.ros.org/users/4418/mosfet2u/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2014-07-18

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It will create the `CMakeLists.txt` file (actually it just create a symbolic link in the `src` folder of your workspace pointing to `CMakeLists.txt -> /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake` in the case you're using groovy).

You don't need that command now. When you create the the package, you can just run `catkin_make` and it do also the job of `catkin_init_workspace`, and that's why sometimes it's not mentioned as you said.

Check out [catkin tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/commands/catkin_make)

---

Originally posted by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) with karma: 649 on 2014-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4